# How to create a list consisting of elements contained within a character from a string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have the following string:

```
s = '{'abc', 'def'}'
```

I want to create a list

```
L = ['abc', 'def']
```

How is best to achieve this?

I can do the standard replace etc and create a list but keeping in mind the length + # of elements of s will change.

Comment: `s = '{'abc', 'def'}'` will result in a syntax error, please correct it

Comment: That's not a valid string. Please show an actual string, with proper escapes if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

If you have situation such as this one:

```
s = "{'abc', 'def'}"
```

Use [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) :

```
from ast import literal_eval
list(literal_eval(s))
['abc', 'def']
```

Comment: Maybe explain what [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is ? I linked to the doc for you.

Comment: @IMCoins Forgot to add link, thanks a ton!